# Update Mongo document in promise after save with _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

#### What I want to do:

1. Send POST request
2. **Save** document into mongoDB database
3. Get it's newly created `_id`
4. Use `_id` as parameter to find and **update** document
5. Write id as parameter in string route like `/api/page/screen/${id}`

#### Problem:

**Document is not updated.** Console.log return `Screen updated null`.

#### What I have done:

First I make a Promise function which is called on POST request. It is saving new document.
Next I call `.then` where I do `findByIdAndUpdate` using `id` returned from resolved promise.

In result I have newly created document, but update is not done.

```js
// controller.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.route('/api/page/scan').post(search_a_page)

const search_a_page = async (req, res) => {
  const metric = new Metric(payload);
  const saveMetric = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    metric.save((err, document) => {
      if (err) res.send(err);
      res.json(document);
      
      const id = document._id.toString();  // make string from ObjectId
      if (err) reject(new Error({msg: 'It does not work'}));
      resolve({msg: 'Metric saved!', id: id});
    })
  });

  saveMetric.then((id) => {
    Metric.findByIdAndUpdate(mongoose.ObjectId(id), // string to ObjectId
    {"screen_url": `/api/page/screen/${id}`}, (err, result) => {
     if (err) {console.log(err);}
     else {console.log('Screen updated', result)} // got "Screen updated null"
  })
```

id is taken form mongoDB auto-generated _id

```
// model.js
const mSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  url: String,
  date: Number,
  screen: String,
});
const Metric  = mongoose.model('Metric', mSchema);
```

Is it a problem with converting ObjectId to String / String to ObjectId or something else?

## UPDATE - solved

According to [article](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/update) we can use `.save` to update document. That method solved the problem.

When first `.save` is resolved I used method `.then` and made update directly accessing document `screen` property and assigning new value.

```js
    saveMetric.then((data) => {
      metric.screen = `/api/page/screen/${data.id.toString()}`;
      metric.save((err, document) => {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        console.log(document)
      })
    });
```

Comment: hmm, is there some code missing here, or do I just not understand what you are doing?
Your ID is a string in the url anyway, so I don't see a possibility for a problem there.

Comment: I think document model was missing there so I added it.